# Element present fails due to iframe issue for getting image src using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

As we know iframe can be counted using frameslist but that doesn't work for me and gives blank output although frame count gives me count as 2. I'm using Selenium WebDriver and Java.

Basically I want to get img source's data-mce-src starts with cid and dfsrc ends with @ according to below screenshot.

I tried :

```
public static final String imageAttachment="css=img[data-mce-src^='cid']&&[data-mce-src$='@']";
```

which works fine using sIsElementPresent in selenium 1.0 but it fails in webdriver using findElement. In fact it doesn't identify iframe itself.

## Expected:

```
css=img[data-mce-src^='cid']&&[data-mce-src$='@'] element present?
```

## Code:

```
WebElement we = null;
List <WebElement> framesList = webDriver().findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
for (WebElement frame:framesList){
    System.out.println(frame.getText()); // returns nothing
}
int listSize = framesList.size();
webDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//iframe"));
System.out.println(listSize);
```

Also tried:

```
webDriver().switchTo().frame(webDriver().findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
we = webDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("html body div img"));
System.out.println(we.getAttribute("src")); // returns nothing
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try as below :-

```
webDriver().switchTo().frame("Editor1_body_ifr");
we = webDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("body#tinymce img"));
System.out.println(we.getAttribute("src"));
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. I'm adding more in your answer because co-incidently found the solution too and finally it needs to be moved to defaultContent() too so it doesn't affect to further tests. Right?

Comment: Yes you are right, after doing all stuff inside frame you need to switch default content as `webDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();`..

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
     webDriver().switchTo().frame("Editor1_body_ifr");
     we = webDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("html body img"));
     System.out.println(we.getAttribute("src")); 
     System.out.println(we.getAttribute("data-mce-src"));
     System.out.println(we.getAttribute("dfsrc"));
} finally {
     webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```